# LGBT e genere grammaticale

Tags: gender

**Nota** Questa domanda potrebbe causare controversie. Per favore siate civili.

Al contrario dell'inglese, l'italiano possiede il genere grammaticale: è in generale difficile utilizzare un nome all'interno di una frase senza specificarne il genere (sia esso per l'articolo da usare, per la concordanza con gli aggettivi o per l'accordo con il participio passato). Questo pone un problema interessante quando si vuole intenzionalmente lasciare inespresso il genere, come molte persone hanno cominciato a fare nel mondo anglofono.

Per esempio, frasi come *Sei bello/a!* sono impossibili da esprimere senza specificare il genere del soggetto della frase, che è considerato offensivo nel mondo LGBT se la persona a cui ci si rivolge non si identifica né con il genere maschile, né con il genere femminile.

> **Q:** Che strategie adoperano i soggetti LGBT per conciliare la presenza del genere grammaticale in italiano con l'esigenza di lasciare il genere inespresso nei contesti *queer*?

Da notare che non ho chiesto

- Cosa dica l'Accademia della Crusca
- Quali siano le vostre idee per affrontare la situazione
- Se a vostro parere sia moralmente giusto che una categoria di persone influenzi un aspetto importante della grammatica italiana

Cerchiamo di evitare divagazioni inappropriate.

Comment: Non mi è chiarissimo il riferimento all'inglese: certo che esiste la categoria “genere”, ed è esplicita quanto meno per gli aggettivi possessivi e i pronomi personali e possessivi (da cui proposte come [questa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun) e altre). Il problema se lo pongono anche in inglese, con più o meno successo. Comunque la domanda sta benissimo in piedi anche senza il riferimento all'inglese.

Comment: @DaG L'inglese non ha un ["genere grammaticale"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_in_English) nel senso in cui le lingue neolatine ce l'hanno (l'inglese antico ce l'aveva e come fai notare ci sono dei residui, ma è quasi sparito). Nota che il *they* singolare risale almeno fino a Shakespeare. Ad ogni modo il riferimento all'inglese voleva essere solo una motivazione, se fa confusione lo tolgo.

Comment: So che molti dei miei commenti sono divagazioni: spero che mi sia perdonata anche questa :). In Catalogna abbiamo un partito politico, la CUP (Candidatura d'Unitat Popular), alcuni dei i cui politici si esprimono spesso usando il femminile come generico.

Comment: Ho [spostato la conversazione in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80156/discussion-on-question-by-denis-nardin-lgbt-e-genere-grammaticale) dopo aver incorporato i dettagli nella domanda per evitare di affollare il post di commenti.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QueerItalia](https://queeritalia.com/2017/05/13/frocie-femminelle/) dice così:

> [...] tramite **l’uso diffuso dell’asterisco e della chiocciola in finale di parola** (in tutte le pagine menzionate sopra) vediamo anche il tentativo di includere tutte quelle soggettività queer e trans e quant’altr@ non si riconoscano nei dettami del binarismo di genere, dato che l’italiano prevede solo due generi grammaticali, il maschile e il femminile.

[...]

> Per ovviare poi al problema di pronuncia dell’asterisco e della chiocciola, tuttavia, **i gruppi tranfemministi queer succitati hanno cominciato a usare sempre più spesso la finale -u a fine parola (che richiama un po’ l’idea di neutro)** in particolare la Laboratoria Transfemminista, Transpecie Terrona Napoli che ne fa una uso massiccio, in frasi come “siamo pazzu”, “state attentu”, “un grazie a tuttu quellu che sono passatu”, “partecipantessu” e cosi via.

In un altro [articolo](http://www.queeritalia.com/blog/2017/1/10/quring-the-italian-language) dello stesso blog:

> **Recently, queer activists and those who wish to move away from exclusionary, gender binary language, have forged an alternative for written language, using the asterisk or @ sign that replace the gendered word ending: ministr*, tutt*, bimb@**. The asterisk has become associated with the LGBTQ movement, as a symbol of defiance against the normative imposition of binary sex and gender, and in celebration of dissidence. It expresses frustration with the constraints of everyday language but also conveys defiant playfulness through a graphic cypher that acts as a wild card.

Riporto anche le ["Raccomandazioni per un uso non sessista della lingua italiana"](http://www.funzionepubblica.gov.it/sites/funzionepubblica.gov.it/files/documenti/Normativa%20e%20Documentazione/Dossier%20Pari%20opportunit%C3%A0/linguaggio_non_sessista.pdf), di Alma Sabatini, che leggerò non appena avrò del tempo.

Comment: Sono scioccato dalla proposta di desinenza *-u* (in particolare per sostantivi come *partecipante* che sono già di genere indeterminato...), si sa quale sarebbe la desinenza plurale?

Comment: @DenisNardin credo sempre *-u*, visto l'esempio "grazie a tuttu"... a me non sembra tanto scioccante, visto che tutte le altre vocali sono "occupate" :)