# Is there any option for gender-neutral pronouns in Italian?

Tags: pronouns, gender

This question is a direct consequence of the recent discussions that have pervaded the SE community.

While it is well known that English has the singular "they" option (plus some more [experimental](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/gender-neutral-pronouns) ones) and that Italian has courtesy pronouns such as *lei* or *voi*, has there been any effort in the Italian-speaking community to come up with some other gender-neutral pronouns?

Comment: I have not followed those discussions. Could you provide some concrete example? In Italian the problem often doesn't even appear since most of times subjects are not explicitly expressed, _suo_ refers both to females and males, and so on.

Comment: @DaG are you asking for examples of the discussion or of the uses in English I have mentioned?

Comment: [Related question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9682).

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguity. I was referring to the question: I'd find the question more focussed if you gave some concrete examples of sentences where Italian seems too not-neutral.

Comment: @DaG I was thinking of situations in which you actually express a subject. Suppose my friend is male, but I'm not sure on yours. I might say "Il mio amico è qui, mentre il tuo è lì". "Il tuo" is an implication that your friend is also male. Although it would require also a modification of the article "il", I was wondering if there had been any experiments in this sense.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for explaining. In the specific situation you describe, the other person's friend has probably already been mentioned (otherwise, how would you know they are there?), but I see your point.

Comment: La traduzione mi sembra un po' infelice:   https://www.lastampa.it/spettacoli/tv/2017/04/25/news/asia-kate-dillon-ne-lui-ne-lei-datemi-del-loro-cinema-e-tv-vanno-oltre-i-sessi-1.34623266