# How do I refer to or describe a non-binary person in Italian?

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, gender

I've tried to do a little bit of searching, and I can't seem to find an equivalent to the pronouns I use for myself in English (They/them or e/em) and nothing for a neutral equivalent to adjective endings. So what do non-binary Italians do when they need to refer to themselves, or describe themselves with adjectives like "alto" or "bella"?

Comment: There are similar questions: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9682/lgbt-e-genere-grammaticale and https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11112/is-there-any-option-for-gender-neutral-pronouns-in-italian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LGBT e genere grammaticale](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9682/lgbt-e-genere-grammaticale)

Answer (score 3):

There is no common way to express such idea, there are some proposals like using the letter "u" at the end (altu, bellu), somebody use the symbol " * " (alt*, bell*). The last way I found is the use of the schwa ("ǝ" and "з"), is described in this website: https://www.italianoinclusivo.it/ (in Italian).